# Restricting DataAnnotations to a specific handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations, razor-pages

I'm writing a ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application, and in several places I use DataAnnotations ([BindProperty] and [Required]) for either model binding or input validation. I have several different forms on the same page, and they are each handled by a different post  handler in the code behind for the page.

The properties decorated with these DataAnnotation attributes are working as intended, but they continue to work even when a form that they are not a part of is submitted. For example, the property with [Required] on it raises an objection even when a form that it is not receiving its input from is submitted.

Is there a way to have these DataAnnotations only apply for certain handlers?

Comment: handlers == controlers?

Comment: handlers as in different versions of OnPost(). https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Comment: Every day we learn something new, I'm sorry, I can't help :(

Comment: No problem, thanks for looking :)

Comment: Quick answer to your question - no. If you want to use annotations for this rather than testing for values in the relevant handlers, you should maybe look at a custom validation attribute.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of just doing the validation myself like you said. I switched to that and it solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBrind, I welcome your feedback on the answer I just posted.

Comment: @LeeCichanowicz Nice example!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: It is with some hesitation that I offer this answer, though a few years later, given that @Mike-Brind commented previously saying "no".  (Mike Brind's excellent website for Razor Pages, https://www.learnrazorpages.com/, and his stellar book, [ASP.NET Core Razor Pages in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/asp-net-core-razor-pages-in-action), have taught me most of what I know about Razor Pages.)

I think it is possible to restrict *some* data annotations to a specific handler.  I was inspired by this SO thread:

[How to define conditional model binding in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515337/how-to-define-conditional-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/)

In the root of my Razor Page's project, I created a folder called ValidationAttributes (however, I think this custom attribute is more accurately a "custom *required* attribute), per Mike's book (chapter 5), and I added this class (RequiredForHandlerAttribute.cs):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyRPProject.ValidationAttributes
{
    public class RequiredForHandlerAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        private string _handlerName;

        public RequiredForHandlerAttribute(string handlerName)
        {
            _handlerName = handlerName;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            var httpContext = validationContext.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

            var handlerName = httpContext?.Request.Query["handler"].ToString();
            if (handlerName != null && handlerName.ToLower().Equals(_handlerName.ToLower()))
            {
                return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
            }
            else
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I use the custom data annotation like this:

```
[BindProperty]
[RequiredForHandler("IDVerify")]
[StringLength(11)]
[MaxLength(11)]
[DisplayName("Social Security Number")]
public string SSN { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

This gives me a `[Required]` data annotation that can be applied to a particular handler.

Edit: For the `[BindProperty]` data annotation, it does seem impossible to restrict it to a specific handler, because that data annotation comes into play (on initial form render) before we know which handler will be used.