# How to define conditional model binding in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to make a simple login form in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, which has an email address field, a password field, a login button and a forgot-password button.

I want to utilize the inbuilt client-side and server-side validation on the text fields, such that the email field is required for both button submissions, but the password field is only required for login button submission.

Decorating the model properties with a `[Required]` attribute makes them mandatory for all form post handlers, where-as I'm looking for some way to have conditional model binding, either programmatically or through an attribute on model properties or handler method parameters.

Is it possible to define conditional model binding to achieve this, or is there a clean & simple alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by using custom required attribute . For example , different button will trigger different handler :

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Login">Login</button>

    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="ChangePassword">login</button>
</div>
```

1. Register `IActionContextAccessor` :

   ```
   services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
   ```
2. Custom required attributed :

   ```
   public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute 
   {
       private string _handlerName;
       public MyRequiredAttribute(string handlerName)
       {
           _handlerName = handlerName;
       }

       protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
       {

           var httpContext = validationContext.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

           var handlerName = httpContext.Request.Query["handler"].ToString();
           if (handlerName.ToLower().Equals(_handlerName.ToLower()))
           {
               return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);

           }
           else
           {
               return ValidationResult.Success;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Apply to your property :

   ```
   [BindProperty]
   [Required]
   [MinLength(6)]
   public string UserName { get; set; }

   [BindProperty]
   [MyRequiredAttribute("Login"), MinLength(6)]
   public string Password { get; set; }
   ```

Comment: This does not work as expected in .NET 6.  On initial page render (a GET with no OnGet method code), the input bound to the Password PageModel property (via 'asp-for' helper) renders an input that has a data-val-required attribute, treating the PageModel's property as required in the browser's form, before a handler is ever called.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Nan Yu's accepted answer, the answer's solution actually does work as expected—on the server side—but; there is typically a client-side aspect to this issue, too.  This is because Razor Pages has built-in client-side validation.

> Client-side validation support is provided by the jQuery Unobtrusive
> Validation library, developed by Microsoft.
> —https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation#client-side-validation

In my case, because the bound input was rendered to the browser, it understandably has the data-val="true", which causes the form to be invalid, because my input is disabled, preventing the form post to the server.

The client-side fix is to handle this with additional client-side JavaScript:
`$('#MyInput').attr('data-val', "false");`

FYI: This will *not* work:
`$('#MyInput').data('val', false);`