# Asp .NET Core Ignore property from different form posted

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

I have 2 forms on a single page and each one has a different Property. However, in my Delete Handler, the modelstate checks for validation from a property that is not inside the respective form... I only want the validation of the **Mail** property to be done on the OnPostAsync Handler and not on the Delete

```
[BindProperty]
public StockMailDelivery Mail { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public IList<int> MailsToDelete { get; set; }
public IList<StockMailDelivery> Mails { get; set; }

#region Handlers
public void OnGet()
{
    GetData();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        GetData();
        _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Dados inválidos.");
        return Page();
    }

    _context.StockMailDelivery.Add(Mail);

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Falha ao adicionar.");
        _logger.LogError(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        GetData();
        return Page();
    }

    _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Email adicionado.");
    return RedirectToPage("StockMailDelivery");
}
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        GetData();
        _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Dados inválidos.");
        return Page();
    }


    var mailsToDelete = new List<StockMailDelivery>();
    foreach(var item in MailsToDelete)
    {
        mailsToDelete.Add(new StockMailDelivery(item));
    }

    _context.StockMailDelivery.RemoveRange(mailsToDelete);

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch(DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Falha ao eliminar.");
        _logger.LogError(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        GetData();
        return Page();
    }

    _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage($"{MailsToDelete.Count()} Email(s) eliminados.");
    return RedirectToPage("Mail");
}
```

html

```
        <form method="post">
            <card>
                <card-header icon="fas fa-plus" title="Adicionar Recipiente"></card-header>
                <card-body>
                    <label asp-for="Mail.Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Mail.Email" class="form-control" />
                </card-body>
                <card-footer>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Adicionar</button>
                </card-footer>
            </card>
        </form>




    <form id="delete-mail-form" asp-page-handler="Delete">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="tblEmails" class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="width:100%;display:none;">
                <thead class="bg-olive">
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mails[0].Id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mails[0].Email)</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Mails.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Mails[i].Id)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Mails[i].Email)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" onclick="selectRow(this)" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="MailsToDelete[i]" value="@Model.Mails[i].Id" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Maybe something like this, but for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515337/how-to-define-conditional-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages

Comment: Why did you put the `ModelState.IsValid` in Delete handler ? Generally, `ModelState.IsValid` is performed when adding or updating data, and you could judge whether there is data to be deleted in the database before deleting.

Comment: @XueliChen Good point. I'm so used to check modelstate on every handler that i didn'r realize it is not necessary here. Nonetheless, it is good to know a way around this in case of multiple forms on the same page.